# Cannot use namespace "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema"

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-annotations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MVC4 API on Azure WebSites or Azure Cloud Services [Error] : ‘System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024681/mvc4-api-on-azure-websites-or-azure-cloud-services-error-system-componentmo)

I have added a reference to entity framework 5.0 and also System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations from .net 4.5 but am still not able to access the namespace "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema". Am i missing any other assembly? I couldn't find any System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.dll file in .net 4.5 folder

Comment: is it similar like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024681/mvc4-api-on-azure-websites-or-azure-cloud-services-error-system-componentmo